# Udoo board + Kinect sensor?

Tags: ros, kinect, robotic-arm, embedded-systems

I am wondering if it would be possible to get Kinect to work with Udoo board (Quad). I have found that there is now support for [ROS + Udoo](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UDOO). Also saw a question asked about [Xtion + Udoo](http://answers.ros.org/question/113131/can-use-freenect-library-for-asus-xtion/) which shows some more interest. It would really be great if it could be possible for Kinect+Udoo. Was hoping to implement perhaps a miniature version of TurtleBot. I wish someone could give some insights on this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Someone I know has tested the Kinect on the Udoo and it works fairly well on the quad core Udoo, the resources might be tighter on the dual core. You can install the debs for everything you need in ROS, including the freenect packages, from `.deb` binaries. Just follow the guide here:

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UDOO

Then you can install the debs with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-freenect-launch
```

Afterwards you should be able to plugin the Kinect and run this:

```
$ roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

In another terminal you can do something like this to make sure it is working:

```
$ rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_raw
```

Some tips to using the Kinect and the freenect drivers in ROS on a resource constrained system like the Udoo:

- Use nodelets (wiki.ros.org/nodelet)

`freenect_camera` provides a `nodelet` version and if you write your code as `nodelet`'s you can run them in the same process and save a lot of processing due to IPC.

- If you need a simulated laserscan and the Kinect is level with the ground, use `depthimage_to_laserscan`

`depthimage_to_laserscan` is more efficient than `pointcloud_to_laserscan` because then you don't need to convert the images from the Kinect into a point cloud first. (Both of these come in `nodelet` form as well)

Answer (score 0):

the kinect now is working with the UDOO. I tested it in the UDOO quad.
Just follow this steps:

http://www.mariolukas.de/2015/04/proof-of-concept-3d-scanner-with-kinect-and-raspberry-pi2/

Regards[image: Kinect working with the UDOO quad]

Comment: Could you give a brief overview of what you did? This helps prevent link rot and ensures people take the right answer away from this question.